# How to get Tweets with pagination using Twitter Search API?

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I want to get tweeter tweets with pagination.

For example when page load it will get first 20 tweets then when we scroll down then it will get next 20 tweets.

I have implemented below codes to get tweets :

```
$tweets_by_username = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $screen_name,'count' => 1500));
```

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460958/php-twitter-api-oauth-with-pagination-not-working-properly/50596606#50596606

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the response. I will try it.